# Is this possible to make a JS request with limited bandwidth?

Tags: javascript

I would like to use a JS to simulate a slow connection vs fast connection to client, is this possible to limited the AJAX call bandwidth in JS? thanks.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> ...is this possible to limited the AJAX call bandwidth in JS?

No. But as [deceze said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366972/is-this-possible-to-make-a-js-request-with-limited-bandwidth/44367021#comment75734897_44366972), you can use your browser's dev tools to emulate a slow connection.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

in google chrome you can trolling a net, please see a image